# Strain gauge installation tester vs. insulation tester

Tags: insulation, strain-gage, tester

An insulation tester (or a Megaohmtester) costs in the range of 500-1k USD and can measure up to G-Ohm and more in resistance. Even a big brand tester like [Fluke 1587](https://www.fluke.com/en-us/product/electrical-testing/insulation-testers/fluke-1587-fc) costs under 1k. Not saying they are cheap, until I was blown away looking into some instrumentations recommended by strain gauge manufacturer such as this [Strain Gauge Installation Tester](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/micro-measurements-division-of-vishay-precision-group/MM120-001164/2503712?s=N4IgjCBcoLQBxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDa4ADAMxUgC6Avg4QExkgCyHYLFMFFMGABsAFnoMgA) - priced at a whopping USD2933! It's heavy, bulky, with no digital read out, limited in range (only ~20MOhm), but costing 3-4 times more.

What makes this strain gauge tester so expensive? I don't see any advantage of that over a wide selection of insulation testers available in the market unless someone prefer mechanical/analog display or big mechanical buttons for whatever reasons. Perhaps I'm wrong and someone can help elaborate on their difference and when to use which.

Comment: It's more than just a tester - read the data sheet. I'm not saying that justifies its cost but you should really compare apples with apples.

Comment: 1) it does quite a lot more than insulation and 2) strain installer is a niche market a lot smaller than insulation testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some megaohmmeters can supply hundreds, even thousands of volts to read giga-Ohms with any kind of resolution.

This "Model 1300 Gage Insulation Tester" measures up to 20GΩ with only 15v, therefore *much* improved engineering was done for signal fidelity.

Comment: I wonder how they even did that. I want one. For reasons.